# Property A, Higson-Roe condition and its applications

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, geometric-group-theory, amenability

Recently I have been studying amenability of groups and property A, and I came across the Higson-Roe condition:

*Let $X$ be a uniformly discrete metric space with bounded geometry. $X$ has property $A$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon>0$ and every $R>0$ there exists a map $\xi: X \rightarrow \ell_1(X)_{1,+}, x \mapsto \xi_x$, and a number $S>0$ such that $\left\|\xi_x-\xi_y\right\| \leq \varepsilon$ if $d(x, y) \leq R$ and $\text{supp }\xi_x \subseteq B(x, S)$.*

To put things in context, Property A can be thought of as a non-equivariant version of amenability, and is a sufficient condition for (coarse) Hilbert space embeddability. I reproduce the definition below (for more details, see this [paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1728880)):

*Let $X$ be a uniformly discrete metric space. We say that $X$ has property $A$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ and $R>0$ there exists a collection of finite subsets $\left\{A_x\right\}_{x \in X}, A_x \subseteq X \times \mathbb{N}$ for every $x \in X$, and a constant $S>0$ such that $\frac{\#\left(A_x \triangle A_y\right)}{\#\left(A_x \cap A_y\right)} \leq \varepsilon$ when $d(x, y) \leq R$, and $A_x \subseteq B(x, S) \times \mathbb{N}$.*

I studied the equivalence of Higson-Roe condition with property A on uniformly discrete  metric spaces with bounded geometry (see this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/244452542_Amenable_group_actions_and_the_Novikov_conjecture)). I am interested in knowing more applications of the Higson-Roe condition, but being a novice I don't know where to start. Can anyone give an insight on this? This is mainly a reference request.

Comment: What are your main interests? I see you have added the "operator-algebras" tag, so maybe you should look into nuclearity and exactness of reduced group C*-algebras. The classical reference for this is Brown and Ozawa's  book. If you, on the other side, are more interested in K-theory, the reasoning why property A and amenability play a role in the Baum-Connes conjecture is fundamental.